# Docbook publishing for different target audiences

Tags: documentation, docbook, target-audience

I like to have one docbook xml document that has content for several target audiences. Is there a filter that enables me to filter out the stuff only needed for "advanced" users?

The level attribute is invented by me to express what I have in mind.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <book>  
   <title lang="en">Documentation</title>

   <chapter id="introduction" level="advanced">  
       <title>Introduction for advanced users</title>
   </chapter>

   <chapter id="introduction" level="basic">  
      <title>Introduction for basic users</title>
   </chapter>  

   <chapter id="ch1">
      <para level="basic">Just press the button</para>
      <para level="advanced">
           Go to preferences to set your
           needs and then start the process 
           by pressing the button.
      </para>
   </chapter>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocBook does not have a `level` attribute. Perhaps you meant [`userlevel`](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/ref-elements.html#common.attributes)?

If you are using the DocBook XSL stylesheets to transform your documents, they have built-in support for profiling (conditional text). To use it you need to

1. use the profiling-enabled version of the stylesheet (e.g. use `html/profile-docbook.xsl` instead of the usual `html/docbook.xsl`), and
2. specify the attribute values you want to profile on via a [parameter](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/html/profiling.html) (e.g. set `profile.userlevel` to `basic`).

[Chapter 26](http://sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Profiling.html) of Bob Stayton's *DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide* has all the details.

Comment: Many thanks. I couldn't imaginge that docbook does not have something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, off the top of my head:

1. Write a quick script that takes the `level` as a parameter and, using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) or regular expressions, that only spits out the XML you want.
2. Write an [XSLT transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) that will spit out the XML you want.

(2) is cleaner, but (1) is probably faster to write up.

Comment: I expected that docbook has something ready for this but as you said basic xslt works. see my other post with source. thanks.